# Create one event that checks for onload AND change

Tags: jquery

I have this code that I want to a) run when the check box is checked. b) run on page load to see it needs to expand the section that is hidden by default.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#hasContractorFlag').on('change', function () {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $('#hasContractor').show();
        } else {
            $('#hasContractor').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

I tried adding the `load` event to the above and it wasn't being triggered.

I know I could do something similar to this and it would work:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    noAddress($('#hasContractorFlag'))

    $('#hasContractorFlag').on('change', function () {
        noAddress($(this));
    });

    function noAddress(var field) {
        if ($(field).is(':checked')) {
            $('#hasContractor').show();
        } else {
            $('#hasContractor').hide();
        }
    };
});
```

What is the best approach to accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you add `.change();` onto your method in the document ready, it will then call your method.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UQDaW/5/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#hasContractorFlag').on('change', function () {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $('#hasContractor').show();
        } else {
            $('#hasContractor').hide();
        }
    }).change(); // .change() will execute this method
});
```

Comment: This is the way to go, I was gonna post the exact same thing. +1 Just a minor tip, you can chain `.change` after `.on` instead of calling `$('#hasContractorFlag')` and please kill those alerts.

Comment: Now all you need to do is wrap that if/else in a ternary, and it will be just like mine ;-) .....

Comment: This looks perfect! I'll try this when I get back from lunch.

Comment: Short of using `trigger('change')` instead of `.change()` this worked perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

I usually achieve this by chaining a `trigger('change')` onto the creation of the change event

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#hasContractorFlag').on('change', function () {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $('#hasContractor').show();
        } else {
            $('#hasContractor').hide();
        }
    }).trigger('change');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
function noAddress(field) {
  field.is(':checked') ? $('#hasContractor').show() :  $('#hasContractor').hide();
};
```

All together:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#hasContractorFlag').on('change load', function() {
        noAddress($(this));
    });
    function noAddress(field) {
        field.is(':checked') ? $('#hasContractor').show() : $('#hasContractor').hide();
    }
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QStkd/20/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#hasContractorFlag').on('change', function () {
        $('#hasContractor')[$(this).is(':checked')?'show':'hide']();
    }).change();
});
```